# get all input element id's from view and pass them to action method in controller mvc5

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need some guide ,
I want to get all input element ids from view and populate this id's 
in an array that exists in my action . please help me to find out what should I do .

this is my index.cshtml page code :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="parameter" id="1" value="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="parameter" id="2" value="b" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="parameter" id="3" value="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="parameter" id="4" value="d" />

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Index Action in HomeController.cs

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and this is my second Controller that I don't know what should i do with! (guess i should retrieve my id's with this parameter)

```
 public ActionResult action(int AllElementsId)
        {
            //what should i do here?
            return View();
        }
```

and nothing else! 
i really need your guidance...
thank you all.

Comment: `document.querySelector('[id]')` would return all elements with an id.  You'd then need to map the elements to an array of their ids.  Then get coffee.

Comment: @taplar thankyou taplar , but can you introduce me some reference about Mapping that correspond to my question?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @taplar thankyou so much